# What's the best way to care for a venus fly trap?

Tags: indoors, plant-care, carnivorous-plants, venus-fly-trap

I just recently acquired a small venus fly trap. I want to keep it indoors. What's the best way to take care of it, to make sure it lives a healthy life?

Comment: someone told me light but not direct sunlight. is that accurate?

Comment: Welcome to the site! To help you, we need to know more about your specific plant. Can you post a picture of it? How old is it? What kind of pot and soil is it in?  Where do you live? What's your average temperature?  Please [edit] more details into your question. If not, it might get closed for being too broad. Our site's different from some others. Learn about us by reading the [help]. Start with the [ask] section. Also, look around at the other questions. We hope you'll like how things work here and stay with us!

Answer (score 2):

Distilled water or rain water, no fertilizer (it's a bog plant and gets freaked out by excess nutrition. If it manages to snag some bugs, that's its nutrition, but things like "feeding it meat" are more likely to harm than help, as will any form of plant fertilizer or soil mix with fertilizer.) Lots of light.